# Is it a bad practice to use nested HashMaps?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Let me explain my scenario. I have some hierarchy that I need to maintain. Find below an image that shows this hierarchy. I will explain after the image.

```
   A
   |          +--> A1.1 ---> X
   |          | 
   +--> A1 ---+--> A1.2 ---> Y
   |          |
   |          .
   +--> A2    .
   .
   .
```

- From `A` to `A1, A2...` it is a **one to many** relationship
- From `A1` to `A1.1, A1.2...` it is a **one to many** relationship
- From `A1.1` to `X` and `A1.2` to `Y` it is a **one to one** relationship.

Initially I had designed it in such a way that it uses multiple `HashMap`s to maintain this. But then I quickly realized that updating becomes an extremely hard job.

Having multiple `HashMap`s means that I have to handle the uniqueness across the different relationships myself. For example `A1.1` can exist within a root `B` node as well. so im having to append `A` to `A1.1` so that I can ensure uniqueness. Now if i have to modify the value `A` then I am in major trouble since I have used that to qualify all keys within `A` as `A_A1.1`

Now i'm thinking that I can use Nested `HashMaps` for this. So the code for this becomes:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, CustomObject>>> _worldsBiggestHash;
```

Is this practice ok? I do have a lot of bookkeeping to do since I'll be using nested hashes but at least CRUD and uniqueness problems handles itself.

If this isn't okay, could anyone suggest another better structure that I can use?

Comment: Using 3 nested `HashMap`s is already a sign of a bad design.. You should consider making your own class that'll hide the nested maps.

Comment: Use a class that encapsulates a `String` and a `HashMap`, and then use another one that encapsulates the former.

Comment: @Maroun I do have a class around it (individual hashmaps) but then like i said updates become costly, right ?

Comment: @ambigram_maker could you explain more please?

Comment: @Shrayas Costly in what sense?

Comment: Okay, since i have individual maps for all of it, i have to qualify `A1.1` as `A_A1.1` means if i need to change `A` to some `NEW_A` then i have to change all the associated `A_A1.1` to `NEW_A_A1.1` which entails that i go through each key in the hash that contains `A_A1.1, A_A1.2...` as the keys

Comment: I'm afraid to answer :-) lest I get downvotes... but I mean to say that create a new class `Example1` with datamembers a `Hashmap` and a `String` and so on.

Comment: @ambigram_maker Even then how do i maintain the hierarchy ?

Comment: Well, now I think it's really going over my head. (Sorry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You obviously want to model a tree. This tree is not necessarily related to a `TreeMap` explicitly. And admittedly, I don't see how a `TreeMap` could help to represent the *whole* structure (although it could be used in the individual tree nodes).

You could create a class like this

```
class Node 
{
    private final String name;
    private final Map<String, Node> children;
    private final CustomObject customObject;

    Node(String name, CustomObject customObject)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new LinkedHashMap<String, Node>();
        this.customObject = customObject;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void addChild(Node child) 
    {
        children.put(child.getName(), child);
    }

    void removeChild(String name)
    {
        children.remove(name);
    }

    Node getChild(String name)
    {
        return children.get(name);
    }

    Set<Node> getChildren()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(
            new LinkedHashSet<Node>(children.values()));
    }
```

(only a quick sketch)

Then you could build the hierarchy like this

```
Node root = new Node("", null);
Node a1 = new Node("A1", null);
Node a2 = new Node("A2", null);
root.addChild(a1);
root.addChild(a2);

Node a11 = new Node("A11", x);
Node a12 = new Node("A12", y);
a1.addChild(a11);
a1.addChild(a12);
```

This would already allow you to navigate in the hierarchy, and maintaining the relationships would be quite easy.

I did not completely understand what you said about the "uniqueness". In any case, in such a tree, each node is uniquely identified by the *path*. You could even create a utility method like

```
CustomObject c = root.find("A", "A1", "A11");
```

to quickly access an object via the sequence of node names.

---

An aside: As it was already pointed out, deeply nested maps (or lists or sets) are questionable. But regardless of that, you should always use *interfaces*, like in

```
Map<String, Map<String, CustomObject>> maps;
```

This *could* be OK for certain use-cases, but depending on *what* exactly you want to model (and particularly, when there is another layer), this may already be inconvenient.

Comment: Wow this is so comprehensive. I'm going to take a while to understand this and get back to you. But it looks like this might help. Thank you, kind sir.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you @Marco13. I understood a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion is not advisable.

Under the assumption that your requirements are to be able to fetch an item in O(log(n)) time based on a key.
I would suggest doing either of the following as a better solution to this problem:

1. Use a TreeMap, or if you need concurrency, use ConcurrentSkipListMap (this would be my number 1 choice for solving your problem)
2. Have a TreeSet to contain the keys, and a separate HashMap to map between the keys and values
3. Create a class that encapsulates the mapping (i.e. a HashMap Decorator), which will handle the unique key checking recursively (again, the first approach is more desirable)

Comment: What would be the benefit of a skip list over a hashtable?

Comment: A hashtable does not support a tree structure as needed here, also a hashtable synchronizes every methods for achieving thread safety, which is very slow. Moreover, ConcurrentSkipListMap enables concurrent editing without throwing ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand where the hierarchy is being represented in the case of a TreeMap. Could you please be more elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: The TreeMap is a map in the form of a tree, therefore, by default, it has a hierarchical structure of a tree.

Comment: Okay, But im still confused where the hierarchy `A -> A1` and `B -> B1` can be maintained. Sorry about this, im really new to Trees and Hashes

Comment: You'll need to have some class for representing a key as the full path in the tree (e.g. A->A1->A1.1). These keys will be used as the keys to the TreeMap. The values in the TreeMap would be the CustomObject instances. You can get to the leaf objects by using the nodes, and compare the nodes by comparing their full paths in the tree. In the second solution you'll do the same thing. However, it's not as elegant a data structure (since it has both a tree and a map separately).

Comment: Interesting, let me think about this and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @eitanfar if i have the key as a full path and the `A` is changed to `B` then i'll run into problems with updating again, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, if the Key class you create is just an abstraction, and the full path is being calculated each time instead of kept as a state, you shouldn't have a problem updating one of the parents. However, in either case, in order to keep a correct structure (regardless of the data structure you choose), you'll need to take out the key and put it back in.

Comment: Also how will we be able to answer the question: "what are the list of nodes under A" ? Where is that relationship maintained ?

Comment: It is not. See my assumption in the answer itself. This requirement was not obvious from your question. In this case, I would suggest to go for option 3 in my answer. Wrap a hash map in a class that would hide all the unique value checking etc.